# Error installing hyperkit on HomeBrew in M1 Silicon

Tags: macos, openshift, apple-m1, minishift, hyperkit

I'm trying to install hyperkit on MacOS 12.1 M1 Silicon and I get the following error.

```
 % brew install hyperkit
    Error: hyperkit: no bottle available!
    You can try to install from source with:
      brew install --build-from-source hyperkit
    Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
    failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
    requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
    official channels.
```

With some research I found an incompatibility with M1 Silicon processors [M1 Compatibility Issue](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/moby/hyperkit/310).

Is there a workaround for this?

I want to setup minishift on M1 Silicon and Hyperkit is a pre-requisite on MacOS.

Comment: As per the [maintainer comment](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/310#issuecomment-1003707160), hyperkit will not be made available on M1

Minishift itself is superseeded by CodeReadyContainers, which in turn don't work on Apple Silicon yet either. It's a bit of a waiting game currently.

Comment: That's really disappointing @Rick

Comment: Good news for this case: https://github.com/code-ready/crc/discussions/2988 there's a dev preview. gonna try it out and amend [my blog](https://yelling.cloud/posts/openshift_apple_silicon/) ASAP

Answer (score 18):

Apparently hyperkit is not available for mac m1/m2. ARM chips.

So, I used [qemu](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/qemu/).

Install qemu using:

```
brew install qemu
```

Run

```
minikube start --driver=qemu
```

Answer (score 4):

M1 chip doesn't support hyperkit.
Tried virtualization using Kind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about minishift, but for minikube, qemu works fine

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/qemu/

Answer (score 0):

First do this brew install --cask xcodes
then do a brew install minikube